# The autofill field name “postal-code” is not allowed in this context

Tags: html, autocomplete, postal-code

im currently trying to optimize my forms on my Webpage. The HTML Validator gives me the following error:

```
 The autofill field name “postal-code” is not allowed in this context.
```

I dont know why, since it does what it should. The autofill inserts the Postal-code. Here is the Element:

```
<td><input type=number name="changeZip" min=00000 max=99999 autocomplete="postal-code"></td>
```

This Element has same Error:

```
<input class="login" type="number" name="txtZip" value="" required max="99999" min="00000" placeholder="Postleitzahl" autocomplete="postal-code"/>
```

Why isnt it allowed here according to the Error-Message? I dont find anything in Google for this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type attribute needs to be "text". Some countries use a combination of letters and numbers for their postal code.

Therefore, your input element should be

```
<input type="text" name="changeZip" minLength="5" maxLength="5" autocomplete="postal-code">
```